# Admob, Funding Choices and EU consent, ads not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

i have implemented Admob in my iOS apps and, since the consent from EU customers is now required, I have also added the funding choices form using the User Messaging Platform framework.
The form displays correctly and shows two options, Consent and Manage Options.
If the user selects Consent everything is fine, the ads are displayed. Otherwise if the user selects Manage Options and then Submit, no ads are shown. I tried selecting/unselecting everything in that window, also the TCF vendors, but the ads are not shown.
Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have exactly the same experience... did you understand it in the meantime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround that you can use until Google figures out what they are doing wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64299305/4089350

Answer (score -1):

Idem. However,  the emulator shows ads in both cases. Dont have much sense.